# R: NLS doens't converge properly

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a recursive nls estimation. However due to ?structural breaks the function the nls does not converge for most the samples. So than the code breaks.
How can i overcome this using R? ie using different starting value, and choose this dynamically or automatically? And if there is an error, continue with the next sample size.

Furthermore, is is possible to see in which sample there is this non-convergence and store this? Code below:

```
   Scaling=0.1175962
start=475
end=774
expandalfa0=matrix(nrow=length(PPPrate)-start+1,ncol=1)
expandalfa1=matrix(nrow=length(PPPrate)-start+1,ncol=1)
expandalfa2=matrix(nrow=length(PPPrate)-start+1,ncol=1)
expandalfa3=matrix(nrow=length(PPPrate)-start+1,ncol=1)

for (i in start:length(PPPrate)){
  tempSpread=Spread[1:i-1]  
  tempPPPrate=PPPrate[1:i-1]
  nlsresults=nls(tempPPPrate ~ Scaling*(alfa0+(alfa1/(1+exp(alfa2+alfa3*tempSpread)))),
  data=tempdata,
  start=list(alfa0=0.003,alfa1=0.014,alfa2=4.1,alfa3=-147),trace=TRUE,weights=weightnotional[1:i-1]) 
  Paraexpand=summary(nlsresults)$parameters
  expandalfa0[i-start+1]=Paraexpand[1,1]
  expandalfa1[i-start+1]=Paraexpand[2,1]
  expandalfa2[i-start+1]=Paraexpand[3,1]
  expandalfa3[i-start+1]=Paraexpand[4,1]
  alfa0=Paraexpand[1,1]
  alfa1=Paraexpand[2,1]
  alfa2=Paraexpand[3,1]
  alfa3=Paraexpand[4,1]
  alfa4=Paraexpand[5,1]
  alfa5=Paraexpand[6,1]
 }
expandforecast=Scaling*(expandalfa0+(expandalfa1/(1+exp(expandalfa2+expandalfa3*Spread[start:end]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your main question is how to continue the loop when an error occurs, check out `?try` and `?trycatch` to see how to test each `nls` call and report failure without crashing the `for` loop itself.  You can put in diagnostics info to identify, e.g., for which values of `i` convergence failed.

Comment: Yes, this is the main concern. Other question is how to choose these starting values

Comment: Well, choosing initial values is close to a Black Art.  Unless you have a good idea where the local extrema are :-).

Answer (score 1):

When I'm using nlm (similar to optim(), and probably somewhat similar to nls()), I use the following code in my bootstrapping loop:

`tryCatch(nlm(NLL_Function, ...), error=function(e){NA})`

That way it just returns an NA instead of throwing an error and causing the whole program to crash.  This is basically what @Carl Witthoft suggested.

I confess that I'm not terribly familiar with nls(), but like I said, I imagine it's an approach to optimization.  If that is indeed the case, perhaps you could make use of another optimization algorithm.  The `optim()` function in R is a wrapper for several algorithms.  If you're having trouble getting stuck in local minima (for minimization problems), then simulated annealing `optim(..., method="SANN")` might be a good method to try --- it takes big jumps periodically (I think of this as a Lévy flight through parameter space), so it might be less likely to get stuck.

Of course, my suggestion pertains to re-writing your code to use your own loss function (e.g., maximum likelihood).  If you can't get nls() to work, maybe it'll be worth trying.

Best of luck.